# Weirdness with showing values of the type double in MS Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I have a datatable which contains a number of double values e.g. 274.6
When i bind to the chart these numbers are shown as 2746 
I tried to set the series.YValueType = ChartValueType.Double;
But it does nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Try settings the Label formatting in the chart area like this:

```
theChartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.0";
theChartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0.0";
```

Where theChartArea is something like: myChart.ChartArea["me"]

Comment: thanks i will give it a go
other way to solve it was to set a differenct locale for that thread